# Need help structuring SQL query to find collisions tied to same key value

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I'm working on merging individual Access databases into a single SQL database, but there are collisions that need to be sorted out first.

For example, the table in each database that holds course/class information (it's school-related) uses the [Course ID] as a key value, but the other columns in that table don't necessarily match across all of the individual Access databases.  So, a [Course ID] of "0106" might exist in multiple databases, and I need to make sure that the other 19 columns associated with that [Course ID] are identical in the other access databases.

I've already compiled the data from all of the access databases into an Access database as an aggregate with all of the duplicated/colliding data.

I've already developed a query to find all of the duplicate [Course ID] values, but I need another query to find any other inconsistent data between records.

How can I structure a SQL query to find records with duplicate [Course ID] values, but only the ones where one of the other columns has an inconsistency?

I have two tables that I'm working with; CHI(fields Expr1000,School) and CRS (fields Expr1000,Course ID, Course title).

The query I'm using atm is:

```
SELECT CRS.[Course ID], CRS.[Course title], CHI.Name
FROM CHI RIGHT JOIN CRS ON CHI.Expr1000 = CRS.Expr1000
WHERE (
    ((CRS.[Course ID]) In 
    (SELECT [Course ID] FROM [CRS] As Tmp GROUP BY [Course ID] HAVING Count(*)>1 ))
    AND ((CRS.Expr1000)=[CHI].[School]))
ORDER BY CRS.[Course ID];
```

This generates a list of all records with duplicate [Course ID]s, though I'd prefer a list that will exclude occurrences where all the records with a given [Course ID] have matching [Course title].

E.g., If all records with Course ID=106 also have matching [Course Title], then they should be excluded.

I'm not sure if I should try to consolidate everything into a single query or create multiple queries to whittle the data down, and I'm not sure how to structure the queries for the data I desire.

Comment: could you post the query that you created to find the duplicates as well as the names of the fields that you wish to check against?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.key = table2.key
    and (
        table1.property1 <> table2.property1
        or table1.SomeOtherProperty <> table2.SomeOtherProperty
        -- etc
    )
```

this would return records from the tables that have a matching key, but at least one other column in the table is not matching - note using column stubs here, plug in your own column names.